# Change voice of text to speech openvbx/twilio

Tags: twilio

I am not satisfy with voice of text to speech in twilio. Currently twilio has provided men, women and Alice in voice for read text. Which is not clear sound. So i want to use my custom voice . Or is there any option to make clear sound while reading text to speech in openvbx to twilio.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Currently there is no way via the API to integrate your own custom TTS into Twilio.  If what you want your callers to hear is fairly static you could create recordings of those messages and use the `<Play>` verb to play them to the caller.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

It might be possible for you to use your own TTS if you can have the TTS system save its output to WAV or MP3.  Then you can use the `<Play>` verb to have Twilio play those audio files.

Hope that helps.